# How do you make the Python Msqldb module use ? in stead of %s for query parameters?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, database

MySqlDb is a fantastic Python module -- but one part is incredibly annoying.
Query parameters look like this

```
cursor.execute("select * from Books where isbn=%s", (isbn,))
```

whereas everywhere else in the known universe (oracle, sqlserver, access, sybase...)
they look like this

```
cursor.execute("select * from Books where isbn=?", (isbn,))
```

This means that if you want to be portable you have to somehow switch
between the two notations ? and %s, 
which is really annoying.  (Please don't tell me to use an
ORM layer -- I will strangle you).

Supposedly you can convince mysqldb to use the standard syntax, but I haven't yet
made it work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, more recent systems have named parameters that look like this:  "select * from Books where isbn= @ISBN"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a lot of information out there about `paramstyle` that seemed to imply it might be what you wanted, but [according to this wiki](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Python_notes/Databases#parameters.2C_paramstyle) you have to use the `paramstyle` your library uses, and most of them do not allow you to change it:

> `paramstyle` is specific to the library you use, and informational - you have to use the one it uses. This is probably the most annoying part of this standard. (a few allow you to set different `paramstyles`, but this isn't standard behavior)

I found some posts that talked about MySQLdb allowing this, but apparently it doesn't as someone indicated it didn't work for them.

Comment: This didn't work for me and I'm pretty sure I have the latest version of MySQLdb.  Is this really all there is to it?

Comment: There's a lot of information out there that implies it is, but the documentation (at least what I was able to find) is not really solid, so I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you cannot use '?' for a parameter marker with
MySQLdb (out of box)

you **can** however use named parameters

i.e.

```
cursor.execute("%(param1)s = %(param1)s", {'param1':1})
```

would effectively execute
`1=1`

in mysql

**but** sort of like Eli answered (but not hackish)

you could instead do:

**MyNewCursorModule.py**

```
import MySQLdb.cursors import Cursor

class MyNewCursor(Cursor):
  def execute(self, query, args=None):
     """This cursor is able to use '?' as a parameter marker"""
     return Cursor.execute(self, query.replace('?', '%s'), args)

  def executemany(self, query, args):
     ...implement...
```

in this case you would have a custom cursor which would do what you want it to do
**and** it's not a hack. It's just a subclass ;)

and use it with:

```
from MyNewCursorModule import MyNewCursor

conn = MySQLdb.connect(...connection information...
                       cursorclass=MyNewCursor)
```

*(you can also give the class to the connection.cursor function to create it there if you want to use the normal execute most of the time (a temp override))*

...you can also change the simple replacement to something a little more correct
(assuming there is a way to escape the question mark), but that is something I'll
leave up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this, but the simplest solution is to monkeypatch the `Cursor` class:

```
from MySQLdb.cursors import Cursor
old_execute = Cursor.execute
def new_execute(self, query, args):
   return old_execute(self, query.replace("?", "%s"), args) 
Cursor.execute = new_execute
```