# python dynamic input, update table

Tags: python, mysql-python

I wrote a program in order to dynamically update a database table but I am getting an error. I stuffed the program with whatever I know little about. Here's my code:

```
import MySQLdb
class data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.file123 = raw_input("Enter film: ")
        self.title_ = raw_input("Enter film: ")
        self.year = raw_input("Enter year: ")
        self.director = raw_input("Enter director: ")
a=data()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO films (file123, title_, year, director) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (a.file123, a.title_, a.year, a.director))
db.commit()
db.close()
```

This is the error:

```
File "C:\Python27\maybe1.py", line 20, in <module>
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO films (file123, title_, year, director) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (a.file123, a.title_, a.year, a.director))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 184, in execute
        query = query % db.literal(args)
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `?` to `%s`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825042/how-do-you-make-the-python-msqldb-module-use-in-stead-of-s-for-query-paramete) is question about why mysqldb use `%s` instead of `?`.

Comment: i still get error as :   OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'file123' at row 1")

Comment: It's a mysql error: 'a' is not integer type, but you are trying to insert it into an integer field.

Comment: how to specifically define datatype for each field,could u provide me any example link please..which will be also helpful?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE test (id INT)` creates a table with one field named `id` whose type is `INT`.

Comment: if i need a string ,what should i do from the above example to enter string?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE test (file123 VARCHAR(50))` creates a table with a string(max lenght=50) field. You can change the column type of the original table only when it's empty by this command: `alter table test modify file123 varchar(50)`

Comment: i did it but still i cannot insert strings it still result in "operational error" ,i think so,it needs a change within the program!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
query = "INSERT INTO films (file123, title_, year, director) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (a.file123, a.title_, a.year, a.director)

cursor.execute(query)
```

Replace %s with correct data type, else it will try everything as string which might break at table level.

Comment: It's not a safe way to concatenate parameter like this.

Comment: why do you say its not safe?